# AngularJS & Firebase app paging feature not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm following a tutorial that shows one how to make a chat app with a paging feature but for some reason the code responsible for the Prev page and Next page paging buttons do not work as expected.

Here is the app in a Plunker:

http://embed.plnkr.co/zxp9wcKaMcfM2U0vAJhG/preview

Every time one clicks the Next button, one is supposed to see the next 10 message in the Firebase message object starting from the first one. Keep in mind I have 28 messages in the messages object. So when you click the Next button once, you will see the next 10 messages as expected but when you click it a second time the message list goes blank.

So when I tried to debug this manually I decided to run `console.log(lastItem.name)` since this seemed to be the critical parameter to get this function to work. So you can see in the console that the first time you click Next, you will see the Firebase ID of `-JX7ZlaB0QTa0Z47eu28` logged. That makes sense since it is the name/ID of the last message object in the first 10 that are returned to the page on page load. When you click Next again, we expect to see a similar looking message object name/ID but instead we just see the string `messages` logged to the console.

So it seems like the pageNext function is jumping up the data tree, from an individual message object to the whole entire messages object. And then when we press Next again we see this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at h.$scope.pageNext (http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/zxp9wcKaMcfM2U0vAJhG/main.js:32:24)
```

So it looks like it jumps to the root of the data tree I guess which contains nothing. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `pageNext` and `pageBack` method you're referring to the wrong snapshot.

When I fix that, the plunker works:

```
messageRef.startAt(null, name).limit(numberOfItems).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(snapItem) {
        var itemVal = snapItem.val();
        itemVal.name = snapItem.name(); // was snapshot.name()
        messages.push(itemVal);
    });
    deferred.resolve(messages);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your messages only have a `user` and `text` property.

In the `pageNext`and `pageBack` methods, where you're getting the error, you're getting the last message and trying to read the `name` property which doesn't 'exist.

I'm guessing you meant to read the `user` from the last message?

Comment: Each message object has an ID that looks like `-JX7ZlaB0QTa0Z47eu28`  that Firebase gives to it when it is created with Firebase .add() method so I am trying to actually read the ID string. This is what it would look like `{"-JX7Z7Nohid6Yb4gYUL8":{"text":"Hey. My name is Thomas :)","user":"Tom"},"-JX7ZAqK5LhMZnQbav2H":{"text":"Oh hey there :)","user":"Sarah"},"-JX7ZFz7K78g6FKWzIrY":{"text":"Hey what's up Tom?","user":"Janus"},....}`

Comment: And yet there is still no name property on the objects. @JustinNiessner has given you a great point to debug from. Do some due diligence here and see what he's talking about. Also, check out why there are no elements in the array (which is why it can't read name on "undefined"; lastItem is undefined)

Comment: That's true that there is no name property within each message object but it's true that each message object is the value to a unique key ID string like `-JX7Z7Nohid6Yb4gYUL8`. I don't understand why console logging `lastItem` the 1st time results in `-JX7ZlaB0QTa0Z47eu28` being logged, console logging `lastItem` the 2nd time results in `messages` being logged and console logging `lastItem` the 3rd time results in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. So the fact is that console logging `lastItem` works the first time.